# BreezeJS and IndexedDB Offline Examples

Tags: breeze

Ok, I see where BreezeJS supports IndexedDB, at least based on an entry on their web page, but where can I find examples of how to architect an offline solution using BreezeJS and the IndexedDB local storage option? 
How do I build this server side scheme in the local storage?
Also, are there examples syncing with Mysql also?
Thanks

Comment: Breeze now has an export for a mechanism  indexeddb https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IndexedDB&type=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze does not provide a wrapper for IndexedDB. You have to write your own. 
window.indexedDB is part of the browser's HTML5 DOM so when you see it listed in the Breeze documentation, it is only referencing what is available in the browser's DOM.
You will need to write your own customized IndexedDB function that handles request to save and retrieve from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Breeze can store any collection of entities exported from an EntityManager into any local storage mechanism available on the client ***BUT*** understand that you are storing the entire serialized collection of entities under a single key, i.e. you are not storing individual entities into a store by their key.

We do not have any examples yet using IndexedDb but there are several examples in the DocCode sample zip that use browser localStorage.  The basic idea for indexedDb is much the same,

- 1) Export the entity or entities into a string via an EntityManager.exportEntities call. ( This returns a stringified json result).
- 2) Store the string into local storage (browser localStorage or IndexedDb) with some arbitrary key.
- 3) Later... retrieve the string from localStorage
- 4) Import the string into an EntityManager via an EntityManager.importEntities call.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a window.indexedDB option instead of window.localStorage option?

Comment: Also, if I had an application that ran offline and a new record was created while offline on the client side and then has to later be synced with a remote database that has no knowledge about this new record that was created on the client offline, how would this be done? What do I need to consider when investigating this scenario?

Comment: Either technology is usable because both are independent of breeze. It's your code that links them.  For breeze, you need to think of storing the entire state of an EntityManager at a point in time and later restoring it from this point in time. Conceptually you could store this whole state after the add of each entity but this would probably be a very BAD design.  The idea is to determine when you are going (or have gone) offline and store the state then. When you restore, any locally added records will be restored just as they were when you stored them (i.e. still pending adds).

Comment: Do you know how to call IndexedDB? The following does not work and I looked in the soruce code and could not find it. Do you support IndexedDB?   var stashName = "my_newTodos";
        window.indexedDB.setItem(stashName, changesExport);

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pull request which adds support to BreezeJS which will add more advanced support for exporting/importing with indexedDB.  Please +1 if you would like this support added to Breeze.JS.

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/pull/22